# Does differentiability imply absolute continuity?

Tags: analysis, continuity

Suppose $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function which is (i) differentiable at all $x \in (a,b)$ (ii) the right-derivative at $x=a$ exists and the left-derivative at $x=b$ exists.

Does it follow that $f$ is absolutely continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment, so I'll write this in answer:

Consider [Does the everywhere differentiability of $f$ imply it is absolutely continuous on a compact interval?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185303/does-the-everywhere-differentiablity-of-f-imply-it-is-absolutely-continuous-on)

I think that answers your question.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by that answer. What happens at zero?  I am requiring the derivative to exist at all points in the interval.

Comment: @Jordan: $f(0)=0$ in that example (it is the only definition that makes it continuous) and you can check that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: I may be confused, but I'm getting $$(x^2 \sin (1/x^4))' = 2x \sin(1/x^4) - 4 (\cos (1/x^4))/x^3$$ which seems to suggest a problem at $x=0$.

Comment: @Jordan: The formula you derived makes sense only when $x\neq0$.  However, the derivative at $0$ is by definition $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$, and you can directly calculate this limit.

Comment: Aha, got it! Thank you!

Comment: For future reference, when you find a question that has already been answered, rather than posting an answer with a link, it is better to use the "flag" button to indicate that the question is a duplicate.