# Sufficient condition for a function to be absolutely continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-distributions, continuity

A function $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous if there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:

$$F(x) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt$$

We know that such a function must be everywhere continuous and almost everywhere differentiable. However, the converse is not true; the [Devil's Staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is continuous and almost everywhere differentiable but not absolutely continuous.

I would like to know if the following condition is sufficient for a function $F$ to be absolutely continous: it is continous everywhere and differentiable everywhere except on a finite set.

We could ask the same question for $F$ continous everywhere and differentiable everywhere except on a countable set, but I suspect the answer in this case is no.

Comment: Is the derivative continuous in between the points it doesn't exist? If so then you have a locally $C^1$ function hence it is locally Lipschitz hence locally absolutely continuous. (Making these global requires some integrability of the derivative.)

Comment: I was asking the question pretty generally, so I didn't have a particular function in mind. You're saying if $F'$ is continuous and integrable, $F$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: If $f$ is integrable then $F$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: My goal is to have a general way to justify stating that a function is absolutely continuous for my Probability class; we'll be dealing with functions that are most likely not too exotic.

Comment: Sure, that is just the regular FTC. But I am adding that if F' exists except on a discrete set and is continuous where it exists then F is absolutely continuous. I am wrong about it being Lipschitz though because of examples like $|x|^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual definition of absolute continuity, $f$ may take negative values. I think it should be stressed that the function $f$ is required to be **Lebesgue** integrable, i.e. its positive and negative parts each have finite integral. Even if Lebesgue is the default notion of integrability, it is still an important feature here.

The condition you suggest - $F$ continuous and differentiable except on a finite set - is not sufficient. A simple counterexample for $\mathbb R$ is $F(x)=x.$ Even being differentiable everywhere [does not imply absolute continuity on a compact interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185303/does-the-everywhere-differentiability-of-f-imply-it-is-absolutely-continuous-o).

It is well known that Lipschitz compactly supported functions are absolutely continuous.

Here's a different sufficient condition.
If $F$ is continuous, has bounded variation (e.g. bounded and "unimodal": increasing then decreasing), and is differentiable except on a countable set, then it is absolutely continuous.
Bounded variation lets us take the Lebesgue decomposition of the distributional derivative; the continuity of $F$ implies there is no discrete part; the differentiability implies there is no singular continuous part.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the last paragraph in your answer please?