# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue integral with another assumptions

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus for the Lebesgue integral, but with some kind of different assumptions. Instead of taking $f$ as an absolutely continous function in $[a,b]$, I have $f$ as a continous function, differentiable everywhere on [a,b] and with a continous derivative.

I've read somewhere, that being differentiable everywhere in $[a,b]$ would imply absolute continuity, since $[a,b]$ is a closed interval and, from this, the proof would come clear to me. Is it right? In a positive case, why? In a negative way, how could I work it out?

Comment: Continuous derivative makes everything trivial

Comment: Sorry if my question if dumb, but, I can not see why. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: Just look at the proof in Wikipedia's FTC article(specifically the proof of the corollary of FTC 1). This isn't difficult because you have strong assumptions. In fact you don't need any Lebesgue integration; with such strong assumptions this is basically the vanilla FTC in any introductory calculus book.

Comment: Your second claim is incorrect .. see [Everywhere differentiability does not imply AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185303/does-the-everywhere-differentiability-of-f-imply-it-is-absolutely-continuous-o)

Comment: @r9m Yeah, I've already seen that it also needs the derivative to be bounded (or, in my specific case, continous in a compact set)

Comment: @Anyway Also boundedness of derivative is not a necessary condition for absolute continuity .. take $\sqrt{x}$ for $x \in [0,1]$ as an example. See the if and only if criterion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions).