# Uniform continuity of f given conditions on its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be a differentiable function, and say $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)+f'(x)$ exists.
Prove that $f$ is uniform continuous in $[0,\infty)$.

I want to use the fact that if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists then $f$ is
absolutely continuous, but it baffles me.

EDIT: An extreme typo of minus instead of plus, and absolute instead of uniform.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/407654/42969

Comment: Thanks! Is there a proof that involves the definition of limit by Cauchy directly?

Comment: Differentiable functions do not have to be absolutely continuous.  Is there an hypothesis missing?  Or did you simply want *uniform* continuity?  See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185303/does-the-everywhere-differentiability-of-f-imply-it-is-absolutely-continuous-o

Comment: You are correct, guess I’m super distracted today, sorry